# Sonar PDF report has no files list in section 'Violations Details'

Tags: sonarqube

I have generated PDF report in Sonar but I do not have files list in the 'Violations Details' section although there are line numbers for violations. There is written word 'java' instead of files names. Any suggestions how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

What is the plugin you did use to generate the PDF report? I believe it is not supported by the SonarQube team and that you will have to see that directly with the author of the plugin.
Also, could you indicate your SonarQube version and if you get any error message in the log?

Comment: I use sonar-pdfreport-plugin-1.3.2.jar and SonarQube version is 4.3. There are no errors in the log:
[INFO] Retrieving project info for my_project <br>
[INFO]     Retrieving measures<br>
[INFO]     Retrieving most violated rules<br>
[INFO]     Retrieving most violated files<br>
[INFO]     Retrieving most complex elements<br>
[INFO]     Retrieving most duplicated files<br>
[INFO] Generating PDF report...<br>
[INFO] PDF report generated (see my_project.pdf on build output directory)

Comment: This plugin is maintained by

Comment: This plugin is maintained by Klicap. You can have a look at http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/PDF-Report-1-3-2-Not-working-with-SonarQube-4-3-td5025247.html and try to run Sonar in debug mode (-X).